# TLS with SHA-2 support

Tags: ssl, sha

How do I find out if a particular client supports SHA-2 or not?

Is this something that can be found out on the basis of CipherSuites present in the ClientHello?

Also,when Server sends Certificate, as part of TLS handshake, is it allowed to send SHA-2 certificate even though any of the algorithms associated with SHA-2 are not mentioned in ClientHello?

Comment: In principle (1) yes (2) no.